# Upgrading `go version` for `CGO` a Postgres FDW project

Tags: postgresql, go, cgo, postgres-fdw, steampipe

I am trying to build the [`steampipe-postgres-fdw`](https://github.com/turbot/steampipe-postgres-fdw) project in a **Mac M1** with the latest `go` version (`1.21`).

It currently uses `go version 1.19`.

The FDW is designed to work with Postgresql 14.

The project comes with a `Makefile` which generates the `go` files with the C import headers (relies on the `pg_config` in `$PATH`).

I changed the `go` directive in the `go.mod` file (`go mod edit --go 1.21`), but when I run `make`, I hit upon the error below:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_res_9_nclose", referenced from:
      _internal/syscall/unix.libresolv_res_9_nclose_trampoline.abi0 in steampipe_postgres_fdw.a(go.o)
  "_res_9_ninit", referenced from:
      _internal/syscall/unix.libresolv_res_9_ninit_trampoline.abi0 in steampipe_postgres_fdw.a(go.o)
  "_res_9_nsearch", referenced from:
      _internal/syscall/unix.libresolv_res_9_nsearch_trampoline.abi0 in steampipe_postgres_fdw.a(go.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

Comment: [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=Undefined+symbols+for+architecture+arm64%3A+++%22_res_9_nclose%22) for the error message brings in [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/58159)–basically, it says linking should be done with specifying `-lresolv` (that is, you should link against the `libresolv` library. Exactly how to make the build process use `-lresolv` when linking is a separate question.

Comment: While we're at it, I should point out that changing Go version in a `go.mod` file has nothing to do with changing the version of Go used for compiling–it merely says hints toolchain about what's the lowest version of Go is supported by the module; the actual Go version used for building is that of the `go` command which is run (by you). You can run `go version` to see what version is it.

Comment: @kostix thank you for the direction. `libresolv` was a no-go, but it turns out that adding a ` -tags=netgo` to the `go build` command solves the issue.

Comment: «adding a `-tags=netgo` … solves the issue»–should work, yes, if you clearly understand possible repercussions: basically, your program will use a somewhat dumbed-down DNS resolver (provided by a Go's internal package) whose behavior might slightly deviate from "typically expected" behavior in some subtle cases–such as (not) caching the lookup results or caching with different TTL or not reloading the system-wide resolver configuration at runtime, when it changes, etc. I mean, you might want to read up on this and figure out whether that really works acceptably for your prospective use cases.

Comment: BTW, be sure to accept your own answer (maybe after some timeout imposed by SO).

Comment: « program will use a somewhat dumbed-down DNS resolver » - Thanks for the heads up. I don't suppose that's going to be a problem, since the project does not do any DNS resolution. It uses the `net` package heavily though. I will take a look if the `netgo` solution has any side-effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `-tags=netgo` to `go build` resolved the issue.

The writeup [here](https://mt165.co.uk/blog/static-link-go/) is a great reference on how dynamic linking works in `go`.

Caution: As [@kostix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720999/kostix) mentions, this uses the go DNS resolver, "whose behavior might slightly deviate from "typically expected" behavior in some subtle cases"